# php echo an element of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable `$var`. On `var_dump($var);` it shows:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (2) { ["stop_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["flag"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

I want the element `'flag'` to access from `$var`. How to do it?

I tried:

```
echo $var[0]["flag"];
```

It shows:

> Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Please help

Comment: What exactly is the class definition?

Answer (score 0):

The first element of the array is an object, so you have to use this code:

```
echo $var[0]->flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is the fact, that the first item in the `$var` array is an object, not an array. So `flag` is not an index, it's a property and you need to access it as a class member and depending on the [visibility](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)  of the property:

```
<?php
class Test {
    protected $stop_id = "1";
    public $flag = "1";
}

$var = array(
   new Test
);

var_dump($var[0]->flag);
var_dump($var[0]->stop_id);
?>
```

Result:

```
string(1) "1" 
Exception: Cannot access protected property Test::$stop_id
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump() shows variable is a PHP object and not a PHP array, so either you access the values as an object using @Zharov answer or you typecast it if you want to access it as an PHP Array like this:

```
  $array = (array) $var;
```

Example(simple object):

```
    $var = new StdClass;
    $object->stop_id = "1";
    $var->flag = "1";

  var_dump( (array) $var );
```

***output***

```
   array(2) {
    'stop_id' => string(1)
    'Fflag' => string(1)
   }
```

Comment: no, the dump shows that the variable is an array. the first member of the array at index [0] is an object, so it's `an array that contains an object`. and the correct way to deal with it is `$var[0]->flag`